# substr C3867 error in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I am doing a small test, but I cannot figure it out why my code has the problem:

```
cout << "Please input an integer >= 1000: ";
string input;
cin >> input;   
string head =input.substr(0, input.length - 3);
string tail = input.substr(1, input.length);
cout <<  head+","+tail << endl;
```

This part gives the error:

> C3867 'std::basic_string,std::allocator>::length': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member   Ch2 d:\codes\ch2.cpp    48

I am wondering it could be the problem of parameters of `substr`, but not sure how to solve that. Could you please to help me fix this? Thanks!

Comment: `length` is a function, not unlike `substr`, so you need to use brackets to call it: `length()`.

Comment: ``length`` is a method, not an attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string head =input.substr(0, input.length - 3);
```

It should be like

```
string head =input.substr(0, input.length() - 3);
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out!

Answer (score 1):

Use `input.length()` not `input.length`

Answer (score 0):

@cj9435042 You have used 'input.length' replace that with 'input.length()'.

```
cout << "Please input an integer >= 1000: ";
string input;
cin >> input;   
string head =input.substr(0, input.length() - 3);
string tail = input.substr(1, input.length());
cout <<  head+","+tail << endl;
```